# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined during dynamic api call angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have code like this

```
doCheck(pval,pvals): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.URL+ '/api/myurl',{
    "log": pvals,
    "val": pval,
    "istrue":"true"
},{ headers:this.httpHeaders });
```

its giving error can not read property of `map` undefined, if I use hard code value for log it's working fine.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This code is not what causes the error. Post the relevant code, and the complete and exact stack trace of the error